# Wordpress Media Uploader errors when not logged in

Tags: wordpress, media, uploader

I have a button on my site (front-end) that triggers the Wordpress Media Uploader, whether or not the user is logged in. It's basically a guestbook where people can post photos. It works flawlessly if I am logged in as admin, but if I log out and use it, I get an error that simply says: "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

I have done a bunch of reading about this on Google but have found nothing that helps. The thing is, it works great if I am logged in to Wordpress.

The files are jpg and only 150k and 300px x 300px.

Here's the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh3df.jpg

Here's the jquery that calls the media Uploader:

```
$('#upload-photo-btn').click(function(e) {
    var image = wp.media({ 
    title: 'Upload Image',
    multiple: false
}).open()
    .on('select', function(e){
        var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
        var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
        $('#image_url').val(image_url);
        $('.thumbnail').css('background-image', "url("+image_url+")");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I have wp_enqueue_media() called using the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' hook in my main plugin file.

What else can be causing this?

Comment: I have disabled every other plugin (besides the one I am building) and it still persists. I can't deactivate the theme as the code is in the theme. Anything else I can try? How to I dig deeper into the error?

Comment: I have disabled all the other plugins and the site is in debug mode and there are no errors. Try it yourself, it is just a demo site. http://www.northernfjell.com/clients/cremation-demo/obituary/mark-anthony-piper-tyler-07172016/ click on the Photos tab then Share a Photo.

Comment: The two photos that are there were done while logged in as admin.

Comment: Anyone have experience with this?